# docker system df - Error response from daemon

Tags: macos, docker

I am using Docker 3.3.1 on macOS Big Sur 11.3.

I get the following error message:

```sh
docker system df
> Error response from daemon: error getting build cache usage:
> failed to get usage for bm9...za9: stat
> /var/lib/docker/overlay2/r6y...dma: no such file or directory
```

What does **not** show anything is:

```sh
docker ps --all
```

What does **not** work, is:

```sh
docker-compose down
docker image prune
docker system prune -a
docker rmi {all images}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Felice's answer:

- Open Docker desktop
- click the bug icon on the right top corner
- click clean/purge data

It helped me.

Answer (score -2):

What solved it at the end was:

1. Open Docker dashboard
2. Select **Clean / Purge data**
3. Restart Docker (if not automatically done)